# What is the most stable cycloalkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, enthalpy, stability, combustion, hydrocarbons

I'm looking specifically at cyclopentene and cyclohexene. Supposedly, greater instability would lead to a more exothermic enthalpy of combustion. However, based on my data, cyclopentene is more unstable than cyclohexane and yet has a less exothermic enthalpy of combustion. Is my data wrong? What is the most stable cycloalkene?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE!
Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions are usually closed on the StackExchange network.    [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Molar or specific enthalpy of combustion ?

For the former, larger molecules have obviously more negative molar combustion enthalpy.

For the latter, hydrocarbons with higher H/C ratio ( 1.6  cyclopentene vs 1.67 cyclohexene) have  more negative specific combustion enthalpy.

Instabilities play rather minor role in slight shifting the values. The best is comparing isomers, if applicable, or to make corrections for different number of "ordinary" $\ce{C-C}$ and $\ce{C-H}$ bonds and different combustion enthalpy contribution by their conversion to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CO2}$.